# Не полностью работает Fancybox во всех браузерах кроме Мозилы. (В ROR,Bootstrap)

Tags: bootstrap, ruby-on-rails, fancybox

Добрый день! В проекте, при переходе с одной страницы на якорь, который находится на другой странице не работает основное модальное окно. Мини окна которые находятся под основным работают,а так же не темнеет фон. При этом, если нажать в браузере назад, появляется модальное окно маленького размера. Сие чудо не возникает если переходить на страницу по обычным ссылка при полной перезагрузке страницы, а так же если обновить страницу после перехода по якорю так же все работает. На что грешить и куда копать? Спасибо.
Подключен:
"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"

Comment: Предполагаю, что тут замешан turbolinks.